# XSL:FO To display page no N(N) on odd pages only,skip blank even pages

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a requirement  where I have to print current and total page number excluding even pages which are blank. Example : For 5 page long document,it should display like: 1(3) 2(3) 3(3)
The current code displays 1(5) blank page 3(5) blank page 5(5)

```
<fo:block-container xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" position="fixed" right="20mm" width="20mm" top="9mm">
                        <fo:block text-align="right">
                            <fo:page-number />(<fo:page-number-citation ref-id="last-page" />)</fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
```

I have inserted blank page via fo:simple-page-master within fo:layout-master-set

```
<fo:simple-page-master margin-left="0mm" margin-top="0mm" margin-right="0mm" margin-bottom="0mm" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" master-name="blank">
                <fo:region-body region-name="PageBody" margin-left="0mm" margin-right="0mm" margin-bottom="30mm" margin-top="85mm">
                </fo:region-body>
```

THIS HAS BEEN DONE VIA THUNDERHEAD LAYOUT EDITOR. So, solution in THUNDERHEAD BCS (Business Content Studio) would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which underlying FO engine is being used. Thunder head used two different ones over time.

Answer (score 1):

This is [not supported](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/2003/01/FO-DoC#02OctDec-0059) in XSL FO 1.1.